# How to add class CssClass and its attributes to RadioButtonList in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

In my scenario, there is a UserControl(Day) containing RadioButtonList and this UserControl is contained in another 5 UserControls(Monday, Tuesday...Friday) and this UserControls are placed in aspx page.

In the code behind of Day UserControl, the following code is present.

```
rdlUser.DataTextField = "Description";
rdlUser.DataValueField = "Value";
rdlUser.DataSource = userTypes;
rdlUser.DataBind();
rdlUser.Items[0].Enabled = false;
```

The markup for rdlUser in Day UserControl is as below...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlUser" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdlUser_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

There are 4 userTypes that are getting created as `rdlUser` in Day UserControl from Database. The userTypes are given below...

```
rdlUser_0 - Normal User
rdlUser_1 - Supervisor
rdlUser_2 - Admin
rdlUser_3 - Super User
```

How can I apply class `NormalUser` to "Normal User" and rest as `SpecialUser` class from code behind with relevant attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop all the `ListItem` elements.

```
        foreach (ListItem item in rdlUser.Items)
        {
            if (item.Text == "Normal User")
            {
                item.Attributes.Add("class", "NormalUser");
            }
            else
            {
                item.Attributes.Add("class", "SpecialUser");
            }
        }
```

Note that this will wrap a `<span class="NormalUser">` around the RadioButton, so you may need to change the css.

```
.SpecialUser label { color:red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

RadioButtonList generates HTML output containing input and labels.

```
<input id="rdlUser_0" type="radio" name="rdlUser_0" value="0">
<label for="rdlUser_0">Normal User</label>
```

Best practice, add your option's style to the css file.

```
#rdlUser input[value='0'] + label {color:red}
```

Or

```
#rdlUser label:nth-child(1){color:red}
```

Comment: Could you be more elaborate? How can I know which child items are there in the database for userTypes.

Comment: input[value='0'] + label means, find input with value and style next label element. @CPK_2011