# Modify ListItems in RadioButtonList from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I've searched information regarding my issues with this in numerous places without any luck. Also, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084088/how-to-add-class-cssclass-and-its-attributes-to-radiobuttonlist-in-code-behind) it should work but I'm not able to reproduce.

My ultimate goal is to disable inputs in a RadioButtonList based upon a certain condition. I've tried numerous solution without any luck so far and in doing this I also wanted to check if could add CSS class to the inputs or/and it's corresponding label. That's when I stumbled upon the post I referred to.

When looking at the post the writer also sets the first item in the RadioButtonList to "enable = false" which is what I ultimately want to do. The writer then asks how he can add a certain CSS class to certain items in the RadioButtonList.

The confirmed answer states that he can loop the items (ListItems) in the RadioButtonList in order to check a certain condition and then modify the specific item.

Now, I have tried this solution before and a couple of other without any success. Also when investigating this further I also asked ChatGPT how "it" would solve my issue. After a fairly time consuming discussion "it" came to the conclusion that this would be impossible to achieve as the ListItems in the RadioButtonList is created using DataSource and DataBind. The conclusion was this:

```
It seems that modifying the Enabled property of a ListItem after data binding does not affect the generated HTML. The Enabled property of a ListItem only affects server-side processing and does not directly control the disabled state of the generated HTML <input> element.
```

So, my question is if this is possible or not? According to the post it should be but I'm not able to reproduce this.

This is my code but I'm not able to set the input field to "disabled" nor am I able to set any CSS class to the ListItem.

Code in .aspx file:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="Test" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Code in .aspx.cs file:

```
Test.DataTextField = dtDimHorizontal.Columns[0].ColumnName;
Test.DataValueField = dtDimHorizontal.Columns[1].ColumnName;
Test.DataSource = dtDimHorizontal;
Test.DataBind();

Test.Items[0].Enabled = false; // Does not set the first item to disabled?

foreach (ListItem item in Test.Items)
{
    if (item.Text == "10") // The ListItems are found as are the condition when debugging.
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("class", "Test"); // Does not set the class to the item in the html. Steps into the code when condition is mett when debugging.
    }
    else
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("class", "Test other"); // Does not set the class to other ListItems. The ListItems and conditions are found when debugging and steps into the code but no CSS class is being output to the html.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first up, I'm not all that "keen" on disabling options in a radio button list as that will in general "confuse" the user. If you don't want that option, then I would suggest removing the option from the list.

However, you certainly can set the style, or disable each item in the RB list.

So, say we have this markup:

```
       <h3>Select Hotel</h3> 
        
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
            CssClass="rMyChoice"
            >
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
        }

    }


    void LoadData()
    {
       DataTable  rstHotels = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName, Active FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");

        RadioButtonList1.DataSource= rstHotels;
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();    

    }
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

So, nothing special here.

Now, we COULD change our code to load to "enable", or "disable" some of the options. If you look close, the data table I pull has a "active" column.

So, let's enable (or disable) the choices where in the data source the Active column (a SQL bit column).

However, while we WILL disable the choice, we better change say the color or some such.

Now, I could keep the above "send in one shot" data table directly to the RB list. I could then loop the items list.

However, since I'm going to loop the rows, then might as well use code to BOTH add and setup the ListItem the way I desire.

So, our code now becomes this:

```
    void LoadData()
    {
       DataTable  rstHotels = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName, Active FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");


        foreach(DataRow dr in rstHotels.Rows)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(dr["HotelName"].ToString(), dr["ID"].ToString());
            if ((bool)dr["Active"] == false)
            {
                item.Enabled = false;
                item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
            }
            RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

So, note how we set the enabled = false (user can't select), and then I added a style of color = red.

The result is now this, and the red ones CAN NOT be selected.

eg:

[image]

Now, of course there really nothing stopping me from binding the RB list from a data source, and THEN say setting style, or enabled/disabled for each item. So, one is free to loop/process the RB "items" collection after binding, or you can write code to add items to the items collection.

So, to answer your questions:

Yes, you can enable/disable items in the RB list

Yes, you can set/change the style of individual items - perhaps to reflect that the option is enabled or not.

However, I don't believe that you can set the class, and during rendering, it looks like the class attribute does not persist.

However, as above shows, "enabled/disabled" and style DOES work and does persist in the markup generated for the RB list.

Comment: I agree with you but in this case the radio buttons will be used in order to choose different variations of many different types of products, like shoe size or the color of a t-shirt. Many of our customers still want to be able to let the end user to know that the variations do exists but for the moment it’s out of stock. I will look in to it on Monday, thanks!

Comment: No worry. We have enable/disable of items. Not tested, but I think a class assigned overall to the RB list, based on "enabled" should be possible. As above shows, you can set the style, but the "class" setting does not seem to follow though. However, as you can see, the OVER ALL class for the buttons does work, and I would think that adding to that class some css for "enabled" vs "disabled" could be done. If not then you might want to have some code "read" the style for disabled items if  you require "more complex" style for disabled items. Above shows red for disabled, so you can set style

Comment: Okey, so I've looked at this for a while and as you suggest this works for me as well. But it's when I'm using DataSource and DataBind that I can't set the items to enable/disable.

You write "Now, of course there really nothing stopping me from binding the RB list from a data source, and THEN say setting style, or enabled/disabled for each item. So, one is free to loop/process the RB "items" collection after binding". This is what I initially tried but could get to work, hence my question here.

When I use DataSource and then bind the data I could not enable/disable each of the ListItems.